# How do I launch a Lightbox(Fancybox) from a ToolTip(tooltipsy)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox-2, tooltipster

the app I am working on right now requires the user to hover over an icon, which launches a tooltip, which the user can click a link inside of to launch a fancybox with the corresponding product. I am running into the problem of the tooltipster not launching the fancybox.

Here is the code I am currently using.
HTML:

```
<body class="body">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="anicontainer">
                <a id="p1tooltip" class="overlay" href="javascript:void(0)" >
                    <img src="icon.png"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    background-image: url(../bk.png);
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-table;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.anicontainer {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 1530px;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding 0 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.column {
    display: table-row;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#p1tooltip {
    top: 440px;
    left: 290px;
}
.overlay {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

First Code I tried JS:

```
$('#mst').tooltipster({
    animation: 'fade',
    delay: 100,
    trigger: 'hover',
    position: 'right',
    fixedWidth: 30,
    interactive: 'true',
    contentAsHTML: 'true',
    content: $('<p class="font tt">Title</p><hr><p class="tt font"><a id="p1" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="icon.png"/></a>Product1</p>')
});
```

Second Code I tried JS:

```
$('#p1tooltip').tooltipster({
    animation: 'fade',
    delay: 100,
    trigger: 'hover',
    position: 'right',
    fixedWidth: 30,
    interactive: 'true',
    content: $('<p class="font tt">Title:</p><hr><p class="tt font"><a class="fancybox"  href="javascript:$.fancybox( {href : '
    product.html '} );"><img src="icon.png"/></a>Product1</p>')
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QMj8T/)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Fancybox link inside the tooltipster content option doesn't exist in the DOM when the Fancybox trigger initialises everything.

Solution would be to set your tooltipster content option to an element already on the page (a div inside of a hidden div should work fine), or to reinitialise Fancybox inside the tooltipster functionReady callback option.

Javascript is a functional language, you can just pass a new function back through the options.

Example:

```
$('#p1tooltip').tooltipster({
    functionReady: function () {
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I reinitialise fancybox inside the tooltip?

Comment: The way you set up your JSFiddle is not correct, the files are 404. However I've added the functionReady option to your Tooltipster instance : http://jsfiddle.net/QMj8T/7/. If Azhral is correct, that option will help you initialize your Fancybox at the right time.

Answer (score -1):

first thing I see : do not use `$('<p>aaa</p><p>bbb</p>')` but `$('<div><p>aaa</p><p>bbb</p></div>')`. It's important fot Tooltipster to have only one container tag for all your stuff, it makes a difference in some cases.

If that's not enough, please prepare a JSfiddle, it will be easier to debug for everyone.

Comment: Damn StackOverflow, even "Hi" is stripped out of my message. Politeness is forbidden here. Hi !

Comment: For the smart guy who downvoted my answer : I'm the maintainer of Tooltipster, I kinda know what I'm talking about, thanks

Comment: Hey Evan, Thanks for your help. I fixed it, i for got to add the data-fancybox-type="iframe" to the <a> element. It works now. I have a quick question for you, is it possible to have an element fade out once the fancy box launched and have it fade back in once the fancy box closes?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you'll have to use the 'custom' trigger though to do things "manually" and use the 'show' and 'hide' methods of tooltipster at the right time.